# Linking from CPT page to taxonomy.php

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I created a CPT which allows the user to add people to the page. I have already created a page template for displaying all people. This page also displays all categories used for people. My problem: How do I achieve that when the user clicks on a category only people who have this category are displayed?

Here are the relevant code excerpts:

**function.php** (registering the taxonomy):

```
function create_people_taxonomies() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'people_categories', array( 'people' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_people_taxonomies', 0 );
```

**page-cpt-people.php** (page template on which the categories are being displayed):

```
<?php

        $taxonomy = 'people_categories';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif;?>

        ?>
```

**My questions:**

- Which file name do I need to give to my taxonomy page so that the user is directed to this page when he clicks on one of the categories in page-cpt-people.php?
- Which code does the taxonomy page need to contain so that the loop displays only those people who have the category selected?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `taxonomy-people_categories.php` or a more general `taxonomy.php` (which will display all your taxonomies in this category - excluding post categories) - please see [Taxonomy Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) / [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

As far as a what you need to display your posts, once you have the `taxonomy-people_categories.php` created you can just run the normal WordPress loop:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while(have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: that's what I just did, but I get an error page "page not found"... what could be a reason?

Answer (score 2):

re: error 'page not found' did you [flush your rewrites](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules)?